# Incoming Phone Calls

Tags: android

How can I listen for incoming phone calls. Is there any specific permission that I need to use. My AndroidManifest file looks like this:

```
<receiver android:name = "PhoneStateChangedReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name = "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Also is there a way that I can disconnect incoming calls from code? something like a black list.

Answer (score 0):

You will need permission for `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE`.

It is not possible to programmatically terminate incoming calls. An alternative is to mute the device volume for "blacklisted" numbers.